# How to set a namespace for an IronPython imported dll?

Tags: namespaces, ironpython

I've got a .NET dll that I'm importing, and it seems to work fine, except when it runs inside a VB or .NET program it takes a look at the namespace that it's running in to determine if the namespace is authorized to use that particular functionality.

So for instance, if I were writing an app in C# it might look something like this:

```
using The.New.Library;

namespace Knights.Of.The.Round.Table {
     public class Knight{
          // Some code
          private void fight(){
              The.New.Library.DoSomething();
          }
     }
}
```

And it would work fine, because the namespace `Knights.*` is authorized to use `DoSomething`

Is it possible to tell the dll when I import it in IronPython that the namespace is actually `Knights.*`, rather than whatever it really is - or even if I could just use a correct folder structure so it found the "correct" namespace, that might also work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only option is to make a C# wrapper that's in the proper namespace and just forwards to the library.

Also, that might be the most bizarre "security" scheme I've ever heard of, especially given how easy it would be to "defeat". Whoever designed that should never be allowed near a computer again.

Comment: That's what I figured. From what I understand, in large part it has to deal with the Sarbanes-Oxley act, but I have a sneaking suspicion that most of our policies here are basic misunderstandings about that law. I've had a few urges to go and actually read the text of that law to see if what we're doing is way over the top.